# Row swapping not working as expected for determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose I have determinant  A such that
$$
A=
\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&1 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&0
\end {vmatrix}
$$

I conduct row operation $ R_1 <-> R_3 $
 So I should have 
$$
A = -
\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&1
\end {vmatrix}
$$

but that does not seem to be the case because  in the first case A=-1 and in the other A=1
That isn't working as  expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why did you put a minus sign in the front? Then you're also multiplying the whole matrix by a number ($-1$). Remember: If we multiply a row (column) of A by a number, the determinant of A will be multiplied by the same number. And if we swap two rows (columns) in A, the determinant will change its sign.

Comment: I put the minus sign because the swapping of row will change the sign, so to keep the value unchanged I put the minus sign.

Comment: I get that both your $A$s equal $1$.

Comment: If you would tell us how you got the incorrect value $-1$ for the first determinant, maybe we could tell you what you did wrong. What method did you use to evaluate it?

Answer (score 2):

It is$$\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&1 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&0
\end {vmatrix}=1$$ and

$$\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&1
\end {vmatrix}=-1.$$ So

$$\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&1 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&0
\end {vmatrix}=-\begin {vmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
5&-1&0 \\
1&0&1
\end {vmatrix}.$$